# whats wrong with this xml file?

Tags: android, android-listview

i am trying to display Listview control in android app and here is my xml file:

what i am doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="countries">
    <item name="usa">Unites States</item>   
    <item name="kwt">Kuwait</item>
    <item name="sa">Sudia Arabia</item>
    <item name="uae">United Arab Emirates</item>
    <item name="afghan">Afghanstan</item>
  </string-array>
</resources>
```

Error:

[2012-01-08 19:58:24 - ListControls] Error in an XML file: aborting build.

Comment: I really hope that this is not what's causing the error, but you're missing the "i" in "Afghanistan".

Comment: nope its not about spelling :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try closing Eclipse, then run it again.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few other questions here on Stackoverflow that may address your problem:

[Error starting an Android program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656999/error-starting-an-android-program)

It's worth searching Stackoverflow or the web for error message strings etc. before posting a new question (if you didn't do this).

Answer (score 0):

i copy your code to eclipse, it work right.

so, may be the eclipse build has some problem, suggestion clean your project and rebuild.

[2012-01-08 19:58:24 - ListControls] Error in an XML file: aborting build.

and maybe your error is not the xml file error.