# How do I play an audio file in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have code to play an `.ogg` audio file, that I downloaded from the internet. I have no errors, so I can run it, but then the app crashes:

```
package play.my.sound;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.media.SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class PlaySound2Activity extends Activity {
private SoundPool soundPool;
private int soundID;
boolean loaded = false;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    View view = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    view.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    // Set the hardware buttons to control the music
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    // Load the sound
    soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                int status) {
            loaded = true;
        }
    });
    soundID = soundPool.load("sound1.ogg", 1);

}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // Getting the user sound settings
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService    (AUDIO_SERVICE);
        float actualVolume = (float) audioManager
                .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        float maxVolume = (float) audioManager
                .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;
        // Is the sound loaded already?
        if (loaded) {
            soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
            Log.e("Test", "Played sound");
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

I think I have two problems:

1. I put this in the `main.xml` file:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <TextView android:text="Click on the screen to start playing"
       android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"></TextView>
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

   And I don't know if it's correct.
2. I put the file `sound1.ogg` in the `workspace->SoundPlay2` folder because in the res folder I had problems, and also, I tried to put it in the two res folders that exist.

This is from my console:

```
[2012-01-04 19:38:16 - PlaySound2] Failed to install PlaySound2.apk on device 'emulator-5554': timeout
[2012-01-04 19:38:16 - PlaySound2] Launch canceled!
[2012-01-04 19:47:33 - PlaySound2] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
[2012-01-04 19:52:34 - PlaySound2] res\layout\main.xml:0: error: Resource entry main is already defined.
[2012-01-04 19:52:34 - PlaySound2] res\layout\main.out.xml:0: Originally defined here.
[2012-01-04 19:52:34 - PlaySound2] C:\Users\Natalia\workspace\PlaySound2\res\layout\main.out.xml:1: error: Error parsing XML: no element found
```

I took this example from "[Android Sounds - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidMedia/article.html)".
I want to play an audio file, more specifically, a `.wav` file.

**I dont' know where I can find some information about the files that are permitted in the MediaPlayer class and their characteristic (durantion, sample rate...) Could you tell me where I can find this??**

Comment: This is the firt error I have in my log cat: E/AndroidRuntime(739): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{play.my.sound/play.my.sound.PlaySound2Activity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: play.my.sound.PlaySound2Activity cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener

Comment: why don't you  simply search in google to find simple answers. a simple search of "Supported audio formats" in google yielded http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

Answer (score 6):

Create raw folder in the res folder and add your file to it.  Then play the file using

```
soundID = soundPool.load(R.raw.sound1, 1);
```

And also see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674101/android-project-wont-build-when-editing-a-resource-file) for your main.xml problem.

Comment: I've written soundID = soundPool.load(R.raw.sound1, 1);  but an error appears son I've changed by soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sound1, 1); and no errors appear however when I run it, the app crash!!

Comment: view.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);. this line crashes because you havenot implemented View.onclicklistner.
implement interface View.onclicklistner for the activity.

Comment: check the tutorial where you took the code from. they have implemented Ontouchlistener. Compare your code line by line.

Comment: Soundpool is mostly intended to use for games. Like producing explosion sounds in a war game. If you want to play a file or stream . You should better use Mediapalyer class or even native audio apis available from android 2.3 onwards.

Answer (score 5):

I've never seen the Class SoundPool before, however I would recommend using a MediaPlayer Class:

```
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(this, R.raw.yourfile);
mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mMediaPlayer.prepare();
mMediaPlayer.start();
```

Make sure you put the file into the folder PROJECT/res/raw/ (or create it if it does not exist)

Also there is something wrong with your main.xml. Can you please post it?

Comment: Could tell me what part of my code I have to remove or change to insert that??

Comment: To be honest, if you don't know what to change, you don't understand your own code. Delete all lines that interact with your Soundpool then read this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Answer (score 3):

Example for playing some kind of buzzer. In the res folder under raw folder I have a buzzer.wav

Method to play this buzzer:

```
     /**
 * Method to play an alarm sound to signal half time or full time.
 */
private void playAlarm() {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,
            R.raw.buzzer);
    mp.start();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: Is this method only for playing .wav files?? Where have I to add it in my code?? Thanks!!

Comment: I've done something like that but I've used an .ogg file. When I introduce a .wav file it doesn't work. Is there any specification about this I must to know? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

first you need to save **sound1.ogg** file in **src\main\res\raw**  directory

instated of direct passing **"sound1.ogg"** file  , pass file  this way **R.raw.sound1**

```
soundID = soundPool.load(R.raw.sound1, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I would always prefer Mediaplayer over any other api.After downloading file save it to external storage or raw folder and play it using the given methods or you can directly play it from internet.**Caution: Be careful of buffering**.
To play audio directly from internet add these code. **Note: Api version >= 21 and make sure to add internet permission in manifest**

```
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)//This method requires android version more than 20
    public void playSoundFrom_internet(String url) {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(
                new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                        .build()
        );
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }catch(IOException E){
            E.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

To play audio from res folder:

```
    public void playSoundFrom_raw(@RawRes int rawId, Context context){
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context,rawId);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
```

To play audio from file. **Note: Make sure to add storage permission**

```
    public void playSoundFrom_file(String filePath){
        try {
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(filePath);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how OnClickListener be implemented, that's an Interface to implement in the class not force casted to. You did that as a quick fix but blew back onto you since AudioManager got running first so you thought that is at fault.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering is related to the main.xml file, which is causing a conflict. This XML file is part of the Android resources, and you should not create a custom main.xml layout in your project. Instead, you should use the existing main.xml or create a new layout XML for your activity.

```
public class PlaySound2Activity extends Activity {
    private SoundPool soundPool;
    private int soundID;
    boolean loaded = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_sound); // Use the correct layout resource

        // Rest of your code...

        // Load the sound from the raw resource
        soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sound1, 1);
    }

    // Rest of your code...
}
```