# How to send a notification with sound and vibration in do not disturb(DND) mode in android

Tags: android, android-notifications

How can I send a notification with sound and vibration when phone is in do not disturb mode on Android Devices.
I use the following code, and it is working when my application is currently in foreground.

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, NOTIFICATION_ID,
            resultIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle("Notification")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("You've received new message."))
            .setContentText("You've received new message.");

    // FOR SILENT MODE
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    // For Normal mode
    am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
    am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);

    mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });

    // Set Vibrate, Sound and Light
    int defaults = 0;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    // defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    // defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    mBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);
    mBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
    + "/" + R.raw.siren));

    // Cancel the notification after its selection
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

I also want notifications with sound and vibration when my app is in background.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you can't. Even notification with [MAX](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html) priority wont be shown in DND mode.

The possible workaround that I can imagine is to use `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` to draw custom notification over system window (FB Messanger works in similar way) : [Creating a system overlay window (always on top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top) .
But this method is suitable only in rare cases and most of the time it's a violation of Android UI/UX best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Ok good news you are half way there.

I achieved this previously by using **AudioManager** & **VIBRATOR_SERVICE** (yea I know ;)

The idea is not to use **NotificationCompat.Builder** because it will rely on system settings and if device is in silent mode, it won't vibrate nor play sound. You have to manually play a sound using AudioManager & vibrate using **VIBRATOR_SERVICE**.

You are using AudioManager & setting the properties but you are never actually asking it to play the sound. So, in your code its never actually utilized.

Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8732433/980917) of how to play a sound using **AudioManager**, it will also ignore silent mode:

Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13950364/980917) of using **VIBRATOR_SERVICE**:

Combine these 2 approaches and ditch  **NotificationCompat.Builder**

Answer (score -1):

If you can get right permissions to change settings of device, then you could show notifications with sound and vibration at your apps. Also check [this out](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6111295).