# Cannot vibrate using android's VIBRATOR_SERVICE when "Do not disturb" is enabled

Tags: java, android, android-vibration

So, I'm trying to vibrate the phone but can't vibrate when "Do not disturb" mode is enabled.

Here's the code I'm using:

```java
Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) requireContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createWaveform(pattern, -1));
} else {
    vibrator.vibrate(pattern, -1);
}
```

Is there anyway to vibrate the phone when DND is enabled?

Comment: How about this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/35700319/3501958

Comment: @hata There's not a clear answer on how to vibrate in DND