# How do I build and run on a physical Android device?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-virtual-device

I have a **Samsung Galaxy Nexus LTE** for Verizon

I downloaded the latest Android SDK and eclipse (JUNO) and the Android Plug-In for Eclipse (JUNO). However when I click RUN, eclipse doesn't or can't find the device. When I try to run it with AVD. This may be unrelated but running it in AVD, I get errors

```
[2012-08-09 11:41:49 - My First App] res\layout\activity_main.xml:0: error: Resource entry activity_main is already defined.
[2012-08-09 11:41:49 - My First App] res\layout\activity_main.out.xml:0: Originally defined here.
[2012-08-09 11:41:49 - My First App] My First App\res\layout\activity_main.out.xml:1: error: Error parsing XML: no element found
```

Comment: what is the output of `adb devices` when your device is connected ? What OS are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android project won't build when editing a resource file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674101/android-project-wont-build-when-editing-a-resource-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem for Galaxy Nexus myself. Solution: Install the driver off of [Samsung's website](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I515MSAVZW).

Answer (score 1):

When you plug your device into the computer with eclipse launched. Does the device show up in the device list provided by eclipse?

If not, you may need to enable **"usb debugging"** on your phone and install the **drivers** for the phone on your computer.

---

**HOWEVER**, it seems like the error you posted is going to prevent the app from running on the phone. This could also be the problem.

> *Kevin Tighe*
>
> I ran into this as well.
>
> If you have an xml file open and click the 'Run' button, then instead
>   of running your Android project Eclipse will try to run a transform on
>   the xml file. It then creates a new xml file with the output of the
>   transform and adds it to your project. Then the project will fail to
>   run at all because of the existence of the duplicate xml file.
>
> So make sure you don't have any duplicate xml files in your project
>   (look at the manifest file, as well as layout files). The way I work
>   around this is to make sure the project tree has focus (or just select
>   a tab with a java file) before clicking 'Run'.
>
> There is likely a better way to handle this (via a config change
>   perhaps), but I'm pretty new to Eclipse and that's the workaround I
>   came up with :). Hope that helps.

[REFERENCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674101/android-project-wont-build-when-editing-a-resource-file)

Comment: What list in eclipse? When I type adb devices, I see the serial number. Where should I look in eclipse?

Comment: Window -> show view -> android -> devices. Click on devices and click "ok". That should bring up a devices window. See if your device is there. If not, try disconnecting your device and re-connecting. If ADB is detecting your device, you should be good. Try the second solution in my answer. Follow the reference i linked for more solutions that could help you. This is a problem that others have had before.